# Rails Links with Model Object Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following table, and I want the name of my "restaurant" to be clickable and link to the page of that restaurant.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Adress</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>No. of Recipies</th>
    </tr>
<% @city.restaurants.each do |rest| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= rest.name %></td>
    <td><%= rest.adress %></td>
    <td><%= rest.city.name %></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

How am I going to add something like rest_path to:

```
<a href="url">Link text</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this :

```
<%= link_to rest.name, rest %>
```

If you have defined a resource restaurant in your config/routes.rb, it will target the url given by the helper restaurant_path(rest) (ie /restaurants/id_of_restaurant).

As the restaurant is a child of a city you might want to have an url like /cities/id_of_city/restaurants/id_of_restaurant so you could try the following :

```
<%= link_to rest.name, city_restaurant_path(@city, rest) %>
```

Be sure to have this in your config/routes.rb in order to generate the corresponding helpers.

```
resources :cities do
  resources :restaurants
end
```

Then you will be able to see all the available helpers for your routes using the command 'rake routes' in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did something like this

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Adress</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>No. of Recipies</th>
    </tr>
<% @city.restaurants.each do |rest| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to rest.name, rest %></td>
    <td><%= rest.adress %></td>
    <td><%= rest.city.name %></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
<% end %>

</table>
```

but now the link is very ugly when I hover on it? How do I get rid of that?